# xdebug: var_dump not printing my object?

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to write a ternary tree in PHP5 but when I want to print my object with var_dump my object is not getting printed totally:

```
   class TernaryTree#1 (2) {
      public $head =>
      class Node#2 (7) {
        public $payload => NULL
        public $key => string(0) ""
        public $is_leaf => bool(false)
        public $left => class Node#7 (7) {
           public $payload => NULL
           public $key => string(0) ""
           public $is_leaf => bool(false)
           public $left => class Node#6 (7) {
            ...
           }
           public $mid => class Node#8 (7) {
           ...
           }
           public $right => NULL
           public $wordEnd => bool(false)
          }
          public $mid => string(1) "0"
          public $right => NULL
          public $wordEnd => bool(false)
       }
      public $payload => NULL
```

In xdebug my object isn't looking like this? What are these points "..." in my var_dump()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [one of the comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php#82419) at the var_dump-section of the [php-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

> Keep in mind if you have xdebug installed it will limit the var_dump() output of array elements and object properties to 3 levels deep.
>
> To change the default, edit your xdebug.ini file and add the folllowing line:
>   xdebug.var_display_max_depth=n
>
> More information here:
>   http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display